# Create Jenkins Job remotely with REST API

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I can't create Job remotely (REST API + Postman), I try

POST:

`http://localhost:8080/createItem?name=NEWJOB`

OR

`http://localhost:8080/job/NEWJOB/build`

and always have 403 error(**GET methods work**).

Here I see that I need to create config.xml for POST :

`https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9410?focusedCommentId=204821&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-204821`

I don't understand how to create this config? Do I need this config? How to create jenkins Job remotely?

Comment: Try using Jenkins CLI

Comment: @minas It's impossible I want to send REST queries from java

Comment: why is it impossible ?

Comment: @minas it's problem in my organization, so we need to use just rest api

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It takes me several steps:

1) GET

```
http://localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json
```

+header **Authorization      .....................                 Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=**

> Value of Authorization field was created when I put in login and
>   password(admin,admin in my case).

After this query I saw next:

```
{
    "_class": "hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
    "crumb": "2ad62df85d23d4c65a25c0b33fb0ef61",
    "crumbRequestField": "Jenkins-Crumb"
}
```

2)Next step -> create config.xml

I just take it from another jenkins job (named test) manually when I :

GET `http://localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml`

+header header **Authorization ..............       Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=**

3)Create job:

POST `http://10.14.48.107:8080/createItem?name=NEWJOBNAME`

+header **Authorization   ........       Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=**

+header **Content-Type   ...........         text/xml**

+header **Jenkins-Crumb  .........          2ad62df85d23d4c65a25c0b33fb0ef61**

> I take this header name and value from 1st query crumb

+*Body->raw->*

```
<project>
<actions/>
<description/>
<keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
<properties>
<com.coravy.hudson.plugins.github.GithubProjectProperty plugin="github@1.29.0">
<displayName/>
</com.coravy.hudson.plugins.github.GithubProjectProperty>
</properties>
<scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
<canRoam>true</canRoam>
<disabled>false</disabled>
<blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
<blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
<triggers/>
<concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
<builders/>
<publishers/>
<buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

After this step I have had nothing as answer, but job was created remotely!